# select table columns only if it matches certain conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails 5.2 ruby 2.6

Hi all,

I have a model which has status and updated_at created_at columns(also has few other columns). possible status values can be 'Pending', 'Enroute', 'Completed'.

I want to query the table such that:

- All the records must come with status Pending, Enroute and Completed.
- If the status is 'completed' then its updated_at must be within the last 24 hours.

  - All other records with status 'completed' with different timestamps should not be selected.

```rb
@result =
  Model1.includes(Model2: [:model3, :model4, :model5, :model6])
        .where(conditions)
        .where('Model1.status = ? AND Model1.updated_at > ?', 'Completed', 24.hours.ago)
        .order('Model1.created_at DESC')
```

The above is a sample structure of the active record querying. This query only prints completed within last 24 hours. but all other status are not collected.

Comment: What is going wrong when you run this query? Please add the issue/output to your question

Comment: rows with status Pending and Enrouted are not getting selected.

Comment: Your question/where clause suggests that is the intent...no?

Comment: yes. its a wrong query. what i need  as output is different. its in the problem description

Comment: Your query according to your question is correct. Maybe you phrased your question wrong?

Comment: I do see now but you may want to reword your question to be more clear...and explain what the current output of the query vs expected output

Comment: i made changes. now is it understandable ?

Comment: What happens for other states? For ex: "Pending" also follows the same structure? i.e only pending with updated at within last 24 hours should come and all other objects with state other than "Pending" should come?

Comment: no. only status completed within 24 hours along with all enroute and pending records must come

Comment: in short, all the records must be fetched with all different statuses. if the status is completed then only those status as completed records which were updated within last 24 hours be fetched along with enroute and pending status record

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
includes(Model2: [:model3, :model4, :model5, :model6])
               .where(conditions)
               .where('(Model1.status = ? AND Model1.updated_at > ?) OR ( Model1.status != ?)', "Completed", 24.hours.ago, "Completed")
               .order('Model1.created_at DESC')
```

Answer (score 1):

So you basically need this:

```
Model.where('Completed', 24.hours.ago)
     .or(Model.where(status: ['pending', 'enroute']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do following,

```
Model.where('Model1.status = ? AND Model1.updated_at > ?', 'Completed', 24.hours.ago)
     .or(Model.where(status: ['pending', 'enroute']))
```

Or you can go through `Arel`,

```
model = Model.arel_table
arel1 = model[:status].eq('Completed').and(model[:updated_at].gteq(24.hours.ago))
arel2 = model[:status].in(['pending', 'enroute'])

Model.where(arel1.or(arel2))
```